# Deleting a variable in pandas from a df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a problem trying to delete a variable from a data frame. I have the first line of code working with classifying routine_tasks with two conditions, but when I go to drop using the variable it drops everything in the df. The context of what I am trying to do is drop routine tasks from a maintenance board.

```
routine_tasks = mboard.loc[((mboard['Down Date']== '2021-06-20')&(mboard['Category']== 'Maintaince'))]
Down = mboard.drop(routine_tasks, axis = 1)
```

I've tried using a different axis, I've looked up different uses to drop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass indices to [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
mask = ((mboard['Down Date'] == '2021-06-20')
       &(mboard['Category'] == 'Maintaince'))

routine_tasks = mboard.loc[mask]

Down = mboard.drop(mboard.index[routine_tasks])
```

Alternatively, use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = ((mboard['Down Date'] == '2021-06-20')
       &(mboard['Category'] == 'Maintaince'))

routine_tasks = mboard.loc[mask]

Down = mboard.loc[~mask]
```